# How to return an overall Model's value as 'null' from ASP.NET MVC model binder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinder

I have an action method that takes several optional parameters.

This ASP.NET MVC actionmethod looks simple enough but isn't working as I want....

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateOrder(OrderItem OrderItem, Address ShippingAddress)
{
     if (ShippingAddress != null) {
         // we have a shipping address
     }
}
```

An `Address` object is always created for `ShippingAddress` because - well - thats the way model binders work. Even if `ShippingAddress.Address1`, `ShippingAddress.City` etc. fields are absent from the Form an object will still be created and passed to the action.

I want a way to make a model binder that returns null for the model if it is deemed to be empty.

A first attempt goes as follows

```
protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    base.OnModelUpdated(controllerContext, bindingContext);

    // get the address to validate
    var address = (Address)bindingContext.Model;

    // if the address is quintessentially null then return null for the model binder
    if (address.Address1 == null && address.CountryCode == null && address.City == null)
    {
        bindingContext.Model = null;
    }
 }
```

Unfortunately this simple solution doesn't work and I get the following error:

**InvalidOperationException** -This property setter is obsolete, because its value is derived from ModelMetadata.Model now.

Is there a way I can make the overall 'Model' from a custom ModelBinder to return null?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the default parameter to `null`? You *may* also need to set the type to nullable as well, but I'm not 100% sure if it's needed, but that's how I use it.

For example:

```
public ActionResult UpdateOrder(OrderItem OrderItem, Address? shippingAddress = null)
```

I should probably note that this requires .NET 4, but then, you didn't specify which version you're running on.